# How to find the output mean and autocorrelation of a non-linear system

Tags: autocorrelation, gaussian, non-linear, stochastic, stationary

I need help with this question. I am sure this is the right StackExchange forum for this type of question. 
Consider a nonlinear device such that the output is $Y(t) = aX^2(t)$, where the input X(t) consists of a signal plus a noise component, $X(t) = S(t) + N(t)$.
Determine the **mean** and **autocorrelation** function for $Y(t)$ when the signal $S(t)$ and the noise $N(t)$ are both Gaussian random processes and wide sense stationary (WSS) with zero mean, and $S(t)$ is independent of $N(t)$.

I know that for a WSS signal, the mean and autocorrelation depends on the time difference, $\tau$ only. Meaning that the mean of $S(t)$ and $N(t)$ is a constant and their individual autocorrelation is not dependent on $t$. 
I've been working only with linear systems. I don't know how to solve this problem since $Y(t)$ a nonlinear system. I will be happy if you can help me with the solution

#### UPDATE 1

I followed the suggestion from @Hilmar and came up with the following: 
1. The mean of $Y(t) = 0$ since $S(t)$ and $N(t)$ have 0 mean. 
2. For the autocorrelation, I used this formula $R_{yy}(\tau)=R_{xx}(\tau)*h(\tau)*h(-\tau)$. 
looking for $R_{xx}$, I used $R_{xx}=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]$. 
I ended up having $R_{xx} = E[S(t)S(t+\tau) +S(t)N(t+\tau)+N(t)S(t+\tau) + N(t)N(t+\tau)]$. 
Since $S(t)$ and $N(t)$ are independent, $R_{SN} = R_{NS} = 0$
$=> R_{XX}= E[S(t)S(t+\tau) + N(t)N(t+\tau)]$ 
$=> R_{XX} = R_{SS} + R_{NN}$

$R_{YY} = (R_{SS} + R_{NN})*h(\tau)*h(-\tau)$ 
Now I am stuck. From the definition of WSS signal, $R_{SS}$ and $R_{NN}$ are constants. i.e. they are dependent only on $\tau$. I can assume their sum to a some constant value, $C$
I don't know how to move from here. I will need to find $h(\tau)$ I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's updated working is incorrect.  Following up what Hilmar suggested gives
\begin{align}
Y(t) &= a\left(X(t)\right)^2\\
&= a\left(S(t) + N(t)\right)^2\\
&= a\left(S(t)\right)^2 + 2aS(t)N(t) + a\left(N(t)\right)^2\\
&{\large\Downarrow}\\
E[Y(t)]&= aE\left[\left(S(t)\right)^2 \right] + 2aE\left[S(t)N(t)\right]
+ aE\left[\left(S(t)\right)^2 \right]. \tag{1}
\end{align}
The OP claims that $E[Y(t)] = 0$ on the grounds that $S(t)$ and $N(t)$ have mean $0$. However, while $S(t)$ and $N(t)$ are indeed zero-mean random variables, and independence of $S(t)$ and $N(t)$ gives
$$E[\left[S(t)N(t)\right]= E\left[S(t)\right]E\left[N(t)\right] = 0,$$
*it is not true* that the other terms in $(1)$ have value $0$ also. In fact, since $S(t)$ is a zero-mean random variable, $E\left[\left(S(t)\right)^2 \right]$ equals the *variance* of $S(t)$ which is $R_{SS}(0)$ in this case. Similarly, $E\left[\left(N(t)\right)^2 \right]$ equals the *variance* of $N(t)$ which is $R_{NN}(0)$; in short,
$$E[Y(t)] = R_{SS}(0) + R_{NN}(0) > 0.\tag{2}$$
Well, at least the mean is constant (does not depend on the value of $t$) but it *is* nonzero, contrary to the OP's calculations.

For the autocorrelation calculation, the OP insists on fitting the problem posed into the Procrustean bed of linear system theory and drags in impulse responses which are inappropriate in this context. Just using the definitions gives
\begin{align}
E\left[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)\right] &= a^2E\left[\big(X(t)\big)^2 \big(X(t+\tau)\big)^2\right]\\
&= a^2E\left[\big(S(t)+N(t)\big)^2 \big(S(t+\tau)+N(t+\tau)\big)^2\right]\\
&= a^2E\left[\big(S(t)S(t+\tau)+ N(t)N(t+\tau) + S(t)N(t+\tau)+S(t+\tau)N(t)\big)^2\right]\\
&= a^2E\big[16~\text{terms involving products of} ~S(t),S(t+\tau), N(t), N(t+\tau)\\
& \qquad\quad\text{and their squares.}\quad \big]\tag{3}
\end{align}
Since $S(t),S(t+\tau), N(t), N(t+\tau)$ are *jointly* Gaussian random variables, the expectations of the 16 terms in $(3)$ can be computed. *Some* of the expectations are $0$, for example, one of the 16 terms is $S(t)\left(S(t+\tau)\right)^2N(t)$ and since the processes $\{S(t)\}$ and $\{N(t)\}$ are independent, we have that
$$E\big[S(t)\left(S(t+\tau)\right)^2N(t)\big] = E\big[S(t)\left(S(t+\tau)\right)^2\big]E\big[N(t)\big] = 0.$$
Similarly,
$$E\big[\left(S(t)\right)^2S(t+\tau)N(t+\tau)\big] = E\big[\left(S(t)\right)^2S(t+\tau)\big]E\big[N(t+\tau)\big] = 0.$$
However, other terms are *not* $0$. For example, $$E\big[\left(S(t)S(t+\tau)\right)^2\big] = E\big[\left(S(t)\right)^2\left(S(t+\tau)\right)^2\big]=R_{SS}^2(0)+2R_{SS}^2(\tau)$$
is the expected value of the *product of the squares* of two jointly Gaussian and *correlated* random variables, and so is guaranteed to be positive, and similarly for $E\big[\left(N(t)N(t+\tau)\right)^2\big]$.

I will leave it to the OP tp work out the details and determine whether $Y(t)$ is also a WSS process.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I did not come to my mind that I could use this other method. I will redo again following your solution. @DilipSarwate

Comment: Is $E[(S(t)N(t+\tau))^2] == 0$? since $S(t)$ and $N(t)$ are independent.

Comment: @KofiMokome Absolutely NOT! It doesn't matter in the least whether $S(t)$ and $N(t+\tau)$ are independent or not.  The random variable $\big(S(t)N(t+\tau)\big)^2$ **cannot** have expected value $0$ except in the trivial case when at least one of $S(t)$ and $N(t+\tau)$ is itself a _degenerate_ random variable that takes on value $0$ with probability $1$.  Statistically illiterate people call such random variables (that take on a fixed value $c$ with probability $1$) as _constants_  and they denote such a constant by $c$. Once again, **NO**, your thought is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put your second equations into your first equation, express $Y(t)$ as a function of $S(t)$ and $N(t)$
2. Apply the definition for mean and autocorrelation.
3. Simplify and solve

Comment: is $X^2(t)$ same as $S^2(t) + N^2(t)$?

Comment: @KofiMokome um, high school math says: No.

Comment: so, how will I calculate $X^2(t)$? I am new to digital signal processing

Comment: @KofiMokome, sorry, but if that's a problem for you should take a some basic  math classes before doing anything in  digital signal processing. This is really basic stuff.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is  $X^2(t)$ and $[X(t)]^2$ the same? I see them as different
I hardly see $X^2(t)$ in questions except for $sin^2(t) = [sin(x)]^2$.

Comment: i will use $X^2(t) == [X(t)]^2$ to solve it, and update my question with the solution I will have

Comment: @Hilmar I have updated the question with the solution I have so far. Please help me where I am stuck

Comment: Hi: I didn't read the rest of it but E(N(t)N(t + $\tau$)) = 0 because of independence.

Comment: ok @markleeds. So that means $R_{XX} = 0$. Any idea on how to find $h(\tau)$?

Comment: @MarcusMüller $(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2$ is called the [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) by  teachers of freshman calculus (in the US). Perhaps things are different in Europe....

Comment: @DilipSarwate I've heard that term before but couldn't recall it! Thanks :)

Comment: @Kofi Mokome: You said that N(t) and S(t) are gaussian random processes but you didn't say anything about their correlation with each other or their autocorrelation. I assumed independence in my previous comment but maybe they aren't independent in either sense ? That's usually stated in the problem so more info is needed.

Comment: my fault. you did say that S(t) is independent of N(t) so they are not correlated with each other.  The only thing left are the autocorrelations.

Answer (score 0):

In an addition to the excellent answer of @Dilip Sarwate, few additional remarks.

Following [Isserlis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem)
$$
\operatorname{E}[X_1X_2X_3X_4] = \operatorname{E}[X_1X_2]\,\operatorname{E}[X_3X_4] + \operatorname{E}[X_1X_3]\,\operatorname{E}[X_2X_4] + \operatorname{E}[X_1X_4]\,\operatorname{E}[X_2X_3],
$$
the relation
$$
\operatorname{E}\left[X(t_1)X(t_2)X(t_3)X(t_4)\right] = R_X(t_2-t_1)R_X(t_4-t_3) + 
R_X(t_3-t_1)R_X(t_4-t_2) + R_X(t_4-t_1)R_X(t_3-t_2)
$$
may be defined. Then, the non-zero part of 16 relations may be further analyzed. For example,
$$
\operatorname{E}\left[X^2(t)X^2(t+\tau)\right] = R_X^2(0) + 2R_X^2(\tau)
$$
by using $n_1=n_2=n,n_3=n_4=n+\tau$.